# How to set session for User Login and Shopping Cart in one webapplication

Tags: jakarta-ee

I want to make an web application that have session for user and also for shopping cart. How is it possible to maintain session of both user and cart. Please give me some references for the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is no problem at all if I understand you correctly. Simply annotate Cart and User with @SessionScoped.

Choose the correct SessionScoped accordingly to what you are using (JSF or CDI).